# Facing couple of errors while creating a procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to oracle, I am trying to create a procedure in oracle, that will have a select query and
An update query inside. Based on ID which I passed to the procedure it should execute the select statement first and pass the result to the locally declared variables and I am updating a table by sending variable values;
Here is the example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB_TEMP.SP_INSERT_PROF (PID in number)
AS
V1    number;
V2    VARCHAR2(250 BYTE);
V3  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE);
V4 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE);
Begin
Select  R1 into v1, r2 into v2, (select * from (select  r3 into v3 from table2 where C1=PID) rownum=1),
R4 into v4 from table1 where c2=PID;
If PID is not null then
Begin
Update result_table set R1=v1,r2=v2,r3=v3,r4=v4 where c3=PID;
End if;
End;
/
```

When I try to save it, I am getting the following errors:

1)  PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
This error I am getting at into command at R2 into v2 before sub query
2)  SQL Statement ignored
I am getting this at update command
3) Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:
   ;  
This I am getting at end if command.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?
Thanks,
Anil

Comment: I rather feel, you clearly need to learn and understand the basics of `PL/SQL` first, because all your errors are very fundamental. To me, learning the theory better is always good.

Comment: Check the manual - it's all documented. Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select` should have a single `into`, not one per value. And you have an extra `begin` inside your `if`, which you don't complete with its own `end`. So it should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB_TEMP.SP_INSERT_PROF (PID in number)
AS
  v1 number;
  v2 varchar2(250 BYTE);
  v3 varchar2(100 BYTE);
  v4 varchar2(100 BYTE);
begin
  select r1, r2, (
    select r3
    from (select r3 from table2 where c1=PID order by c2 desc)
    where rownum=1), r4
  into v1, v2, v3, v4
  from table1
  where c2=PID;

  if PID is not null then
    update result_table set r1=v1, r2=v2, r3=v3, r4=v4
    where c3=PID;
  end if;
end;
/
```

But if PID is null, which seems to be allowed from the `if`, then the `select` won't find any rows in `table1`, so you'll get a no-data-found exception. If `c2` isn't unique you could get a too-many-rows exception. And the sub-select to get `r3` could probably be done as a join instead.

You also don't really need the separate select and update; you could do a correlated update, and avoid PL/SQL altogether, but that's a bit beyond the scope of the question.

As commenters have said, these are pretty basic and fundamental things, so you should make sure you understand how this works and [refer to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm) or a tutorial to get started - there are plenty of examples, both in the docs and across the Internet.

Comment: Hi Alex ,
Thanks for your reply I have done as you said now I am facing one more problem 
In sub query inside select statement I need to use both order by and rownum=1 as bellow. 
select r1, r2, (select r3 from table2 where c1=PID and rownum=1 order by C2 DESC), r4
  into v1, v2, v3, v4
  from table1
  where c2=PID;

Now I am getting  “ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis “ error at order command can you please help  me.

Comment: @user3852515 - updated. You have to order a subquery before applying the rownum filter, which makes that even uglier.